# Conditional probability, throwing dice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

There is a box with $n$ dice: $k$ of them are true, and $n - k$ unfair with $6$ on each one of the walls. We draw $m$ times (with replacement) one die and make a throw. Compute probability, that all drawn dice are fair provided that only $6$ were obtained (during these $m$ throws).

So:

$A\ - $ dice are fair

$B\ - $ only $6$ were thrown

$\Bbb P(A|B)=\frac{\Bbb P(A \cap B)}{\Bbb P(B)}$

where:

$\Bbb P(B) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m{m \choose i}(\frac{k}{n})^i(\frac{n-k}{n})^{m-i}(\frac{1}{6})^i(\frac{6}{6})^{m-i}$

and $i$ is a number of fair dice;

$\Bbb P(A\cap B) = (\frac{k}{n})^m(\frac{1}{6})^m$

Am I correct?

Comment: The question does not clearly state whether we are picking a die with replacement. I am assuming that's the case though. So to clarify,  do we put the die back into the mix after the throw and then pick one randomly again? Also note that the question states _that a drawn dice is fair_. What you are finding is the probability that all $m$ times we drew a fair die. Not sure if that is what the question intends.

Comment: @MathLover correct. We draw with replacement. And you are right, I've made changes.

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson so what I did is not correct?

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson well I think I am, as the order of fair dices matters, for example $(fair, fair, unfair)$ is distinguishable from $(fair, unfair, fair)$.

Comment: *dice* is plural; *die* is singular

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson because it is a law of total probability, getting only $6$ is. I can get $6$ $m$ times by combining a number of fair and unfair dice.

Comment: with the edit to the question, your work is correct

Comment: @MathLover thank you!

Comment: But the only thing to notice is that you can simplify the expression $P(B)$

Comment: Okay I was reading the binomial differently but the way I wrote it out would end up the same way.  As long as you've got your theory down, great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your work is correct, you can simplify $P(B)$. Note that the probability of $6$ in a throw for a randomly picked die is,

$p =  \frac{k}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{6} + \frac{n-k}{n} \cdot 1 = 1 - \frac56 \cdot \frac k n$ $ \left(\frac56 \cdot \frac k n \text { is the probability of not getting $6$} \text { in a throw } \right)$

So probability of $m$ consecutive $6$ in $m$ throws is,

$P(B) = p^m = (1 - \frac56 \cdot \frac k n)^m $

The binomial expansion of this is same as the summation you wrote for $P(B)$.

Comment: came to the same conclusion, thank you!